# How do you allow users to select multiple options in a select tag in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, select

I am trying to create a component called SelectMultiple.

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

const SelectMultiple = () => {
  const [skills, setSkills] = useState([]);

  const handleChange = event => {
    const { value } = event.target;

    const indexOfValue = skills.indexOf(value);

    if (indexOfValue === -1) {
      setSkills([...skills, value]);
    } else {
      setSkills(skills.filter(skill => skill !== value));
    }
  };

  return (
    <select multiple={true} value={skills} onChange={handleChange}>
      <option value="HTML">HTML</option>
      <option value="CSS">CSS</option>
      <option value="JavaScript">JavaScript</option>
    </select>
  );
};

export default SelectMultiple;
```

When I run this code, click HTML, HTML is selected, click HTML again, obviously, it does not unselect because onChange event has not fired.

What is the best way to get around this? Should I use a ref instead? What is the best practice for this kind of multi-select component?

Comment: Is there a reason you want to spin up your own code?  `react-select` already supports this out of the box: https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select

Comment: @Kyle I'm a minimalist. Thanks for sharing `react-select` I will take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the selected items through event.target.selectedOptions.

```
function SelectMultiple () {
  const [skills, setSkills] = useState([]);

  const handleChange = event => {

    var selectedSkills = Array.from(event.target.selectedOptions, (item) => item.value)

    setSkills(selectedSkills);
  };

  return (
    <>
    <select multiple={true} value={skills} onChange={handleChange}>
      <option value="HTML">HTML</option>
      <option value="CSS">CSS</option>
      <option value="JavaScript">JavaScript</option>
    </select>
    <hr />
     Selected Skills{JSON.stringify(skills)}
    </>
  );
}
```

Codesandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/select-multiple-5w0tw

Comment: Thank you for answering. Your component will only allow the user to select one skill.

Comment: No, you can select multiple items with Ctrl

Comment: @hugojavadi  you can try it works like this:   const [skills, setSkills] = useState(["CSS","JavaScript"]);    or just use Ctrl key in keyboard

Comment: @hugojavadi  you can read the  Selecting multiple options in this link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select     this is the way how we choose multiple options.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe I'm not understanding the question correctly, but you should be able to change the onChange to onClick. Does that do what you want?

```
const SelectMultiple = () => {
  const [skills, setSkills] = useState([]);
  console.log("hit");
  const handleChange = event => {
    const { value } = event.target;
    const indexOfValue = skills.indexOf(value);
    console.log(indexOfValue, value);
    if (indexOfValue === -1) {
      setSkills([...skills, value]);
    } else {
      setSkills(skills.filter(skill => skill !== value));
    }
  };
  console.log(skills);

  return (
    <select multiple={true} value={skills} onClick={handleChange}>
      <option value="HTML">HTML</option>
      <option value="CSS">CSS</option>
      <option value="JavaScript">JavaScript</option>
    </select>
  );
};

export default SelectMultiple;
```